# Packaging wearable app using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, export, wear-os

i have read all posts that talk about packaging wear and I've tryed everything and 
 nothing works, the wearapp never gets installed on the watch.

Both handheld and wear apps are working perfectly on debug using eclipse, they comunicate, send data, messages...

They have the same package name, permissions, versionCode and versionName

Here is my handheld AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wearable"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.wearable.beta.app"
            android:value="@xml/wearable_app_desc"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".ListenerService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Here is my wear AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wearable"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="20"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Co" />
        <activity android:name=".Vo" />
        <activity android:name=".Se" />

        <service
            android:name=".ListenerService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

    </manifest>
```

I exported and signed the wear apk and put it in the res/raw/wearapp.apk directory on my  handheld project.

Also created in /res/xml folder of my handheld project, the file wearable_app_desc.xml
 And added the meta-data in the AndroidManifest.xml of my handheld:
 Here is the added line:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.wearable.beta.app"
            android:value="@xml/wearable_app_desc"/>
```

Here is my wearable_app_desc.xml

```
<wearableApp package="com.sendwhatsappwear">
        <versionCode>1</versionCode>
        <versionName>1.0</versionName>
        <rawPathResId>wearapp</rawPathResId>
</wearableApp>
```

After doing all this, i exported and signed the handheld apk, put it on my SD and try to  install; It installed on my phone, but not in my watch.

```
 Thank you so much for your help!
```

Comment: Why is your package in `<wearableApp ...>` provided as "com.sendwhatsappwear" instead of "com.wearable" as defined in both manifests?

Comment: thats a copy&paste mistake from another version, but that is not the problem, that part works just fine thank you.

Did you know if someone suceed packaging a wearable app using eclipse? Or should I import my project into Android Studio?

Comment: I managed to successfully package wearable app using eclipse (only for tests few months ago -  I haven't used eclipse since then). 1. Do you use the same keys to sign both apks? 2. Have you uninstalled the previously installed (from eclipse with debug cert) wearable app from the watch?